# Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically. error when trying to deploy/push files to heroku - any fixes?

Tags: python, linux, heroku, cloud, buildpack

I have a Python trading bot which I want to run in cloud with the help of Heroku. The Python code works just fine, but when I try to push the files after add and commit, I am getting error which says `heroku cannot detect the buildpack` and `heroku pre-receive hook declined`

I tried to fix it, but nothing seems to work. But then I tried to deploy not by pushing it from my computer, but by uploading it to GitHub and connecting my GitHub account to Heroku account.

Connecting both accounts went well, but I get this error when I tried to deploy the files:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
 !     No default language could be detected for this app.
            HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
            See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
 !     Push failed
```

The error seems pretty straight forward and directs us to visit a website. I did try some of the stuff mentioned in the website, but maybe I am doing it wrong.

Till now what I understand is Heroku is not able to detect the language I am using which is Python. How can I fix this?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#recognizing-a-python-app

Comment: I checked the website you reffered and understood i need requirments.txt file which i added. Thanks for the reply. everything is fixed. But what should i add inside this textfile??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a pretty simple solution if you have the access to the Heroku account used to deploy this app.

Direct to the app page and go under the **Settings** tab, you should be able to find a **Buildpacks** section where you can add your buildpack if not detected automatically during deployment.

Click **Add Buildpack** and choose **Python** as your custom buildpack. Problem should be solved.

P.S. If you don't have **requirements.txt** in your folder, consider adding all the packages along with their versions used for your Python Flask app to this file. For example:

```
Flask==2.0.2
Flask-Admin==1.5.8
Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
Flask-DebugToolbar==0.11.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
Flask-WTF==1.0.0
```

Comment: I had already added the python build pack and requirements.txt. Still nothing worked. Turns out I spelled requirements.txt file wrong. Thank you for clear explanation.